# How can I define my own scoring strategy sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search

I would like to define a new scoring in GridSearchCV as it is said here http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#implementing-your-own-scoring-object . This is my code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
def pe_score(estimator,x,y):
    clf=estimator
    clf.fit(x,y)
    z=clf.predict(x)
    pe=prob_error(z, y)
    return pe

pe_error=pe_score(SVC(),xTrain,yTrain)
grid = GridSearchCV(SVC(), param_grid={'kernel':('linear', 'rbf'), 'C':[1, 10, 100,1000,10000]}, scoring=pe_error)
```

where *prob_error(z,y)* is the function that computes the error which I would like to minimize, being *z* the prediction of the training set and *y* the true values of the training set. However, I got the following error:

```
---> 18 clf.fit(xTrain, yTrain)
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

I don't know if the format of *pe_error* it is well defined. How can I solve it? Thank you.

Comment: Your code contains `scoring=ftwo_scorer` which makes me think you're not showing all of the relevant sections of source code. What is this scorer function?

Comment: @ely sorry, I have copied badly the code, but the error is given by the edited code.

Comment: In this code block, you're also not importing `SVC`, which means there is still more code that you're not revealing. The particular error you show suggests there is a whole different way in which you are invoking `clf.fit`. The best thing would be to just put all of the code here without trying to extract the part that you currently suspect is in error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Score functions should have the format score_func(y, y_pred, **kwargs)

You can then use the make_scorer function to take your scoring function and get it to work with GridSearchCV.

So, in this case it would be:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer

clf = estimator
clf.fit(x,y)
z = clf.predict(x)

def pe_score(y, y_pred):
    pe = prob_error(y_pred, y)
    return pe

pe_error = make_scorer(pe_score)
grid = GridSearchCV(SVC(), param_grid={'kernel':('linear', 'rbf'), 'C':[1, 10, 100,1000,10000]}, scoring= pe_error)
```

(I'm assuming you have prob_error implemented or imported somewhere else in your code)

Documentation: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html

Comment: Ok, one question, as I have to minimize the error should I write?:
    pe_error = make_scorer(pe_score, greater_is_better=False)